# Importing XML File Using SSIS resultset Property issues

Tags: sql, xml, ssis

I am trying to use the below script to import an xml file into a table using SSIS and I have errors around the resultset property settings.

my script is:

```
  INSERT INTO tempXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, 
GETDATE() FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'L:\FilenameVariable' SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

Can anyone advise how the resultset property should be set up?
It will only give a single row resultset but none of the options seem to work.
I have an ssis variable called "blob" that the resultset should go into and I have assigned that as follows:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Dave

Comment: in the General tab what is your ResultSet setting set to?  What is the variable type blob?

Comment: Plus your script is inserting into a tempXML table, you are not returning anything from your script that would be able to be returned to the result set and put into a variable.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting in touch. I solved it, i had missed a couple of single quotes around the file name variable.